# Inserting string from xargs into another string

Tags: unix, sed, awk

Say I have some command that outputs a bunch of strings. The output from this command could look something like:

```
...
foo
bar
blargh
...
```

Say I have some set string

```
myString$Blah
```

I want to insert each of the strings where the $ is in the output of the command such that I end up with a file that looks like this:

```
...
myStringfooBlah
myStringbarBlah
myStringblarghBlah
...
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? (Awk and sed preferred)

Answer (score 13):

You don't even need `sed` or `awk`.

`xargs` can do this: with: `-L1 -I '$' echo 'myString$Blah'`

```
$ cat x.list
foo
bar
blargh
$ cat x.list | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -L1 -I '$' echo 'myString$Blah'
myStringfooBlah
myStringbarBlah
myStringblarghBlah
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use the format string `myString&Blah`, with an ampersand instead of the dollar sign, pipe your output into this:

```
sed "s/.*/$format/"
```

This works because the `&` is used as an "insert match here" operator in the replacement string. The regex matches the entire line, so it will insert the whole line at the `&`.

It is important to use the double quotes to allow expansion of the format string.

If you really need to use the ampersand, use this:

```
sed "s/.*/$(echo "$format" | tr '$' '&')/"
```

The quotes around $format are important if you have whitespace in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely in the shell (`bash`, at least) without too much trouble. Here's a script that does that:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern="$1"
input_file="$2"
output_file="$3"

saved_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
# Store each line of the input file into an array named 'lines'.
lines=($(< $input_file))
IFS="$saved_IFS"

# Truncate output file, if any.
cat /dev/null > $output_file

# Substitute each line into the pattern, and write to output file.
for ln in "${lines[@]}"
do
  echo ${pattern/$/$ln} >> $output_file
done
```

Supposing this script is called `script`, and you have a file called `in.txt` with one string per line, then running `script in.txt out.txt` would give you the desired output in `out.txt`.